# Rails User Login Error: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, csrf

I have a problem with the user login to my rails app in production env. Whenever the user tries to login, receive the following error message:

[image]
Although same 
Application Controller:

```
Application Controller:
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    end
```

When checked, I noticed CSRF related error messages in the production.log file. This problem is faced on the production environment (unicorn) and does not exists in the development environment (rails -s).

Layout Template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Site</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

W, [2018-09-21T13:55:13.032519 #20667]  WARN -- : [c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f] Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
F, [2018-09-21T13:55:13.033892 #20667] FATAL -- : [c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f]   
F, [2018-09-21T13:55:13.034023 #20667] FATAL -- : [c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f] ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionControl
ler::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
F, [2018-09-21T13:55:13.034040 #20667] FATAL -- : [c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f]   
F, [2018-09-21T13:55:13.034063 #20667] FATAL -- : [c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/request_fo
rgery_protection.rb:195:in `handle_unverified_request'
[c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:223:in `handle_unverified_requ
est'
[c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f] devise (4.5.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `handle_unverified_request'
[c1cb8958-e963-43ba-8bdd-d5f38eb3394f] actionpack (5.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:218:in `verify_authenticity_to
ken'
```

Any idea what might be the root cause?

Comment: what Rails version are you on?

Comment: check the form(in browser source code) whether csrf token is available or not in form tag.
Refer for more: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html 
https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-csrf-protection-in-rails-19fa0a42c0ef

Comment: Rails version 5.0.7

Comment: Csrf token code exists in the form code and even posted to the server with user &pwd  when the form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Check the existence of `secret_key_base` in `config\secrets.yml`.

Check that you have `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]` (`$SECRET_KEY_BASE`) set in production.

[#csrf_meta_tags](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper.html#method-i-csrf_meta_tags) depends on `secret_key_base` to verify the token.

Check that you have [asset fingerprinting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) turned on and you are not caching the old page after a release.

Check [`config.assets.digest = true`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) for production.

> The fingerprinting behavior is controlled by the config.assets.digest initialization option (which defaults to true for production and false for everything else).

It's probably missing, so relies on defaults, so check that `$RAILS_ENV = production`.

Comment: config/secrets.yml includes development, test and production keys.

development:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXX

test:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXX

production:
  secret_key_base: XXXXXXX

#  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

Comment: OK then turn on debug logging in production, and also add a `before_action` filter which prints out `params["authenticity_token"]` to verify it exists. Also upload a minimal working example of the bug to GitHub and post the link in the question.

Comment: How did you generate the `secret_key_base` for production? Are you sure the key is the exact length and encoding it needs to be in?

Comment: Also read this section for clues. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Answer (score 0):

Probably not exactly the problem you're having, since your `protect_from_forgery` is at the top of the ApplicationController, but maybe helpful for others:

I had a call to the `devise_parameter_sanitizer` in a before action `if: devise_controller?` *above* the `protect_from_forgery`-line, which caused Devise to break after a rails upgrade to 5.2. As Rails 5.2  does `protect_from_forgery` by default (if you're using the default 5.2 settings), I was able to remove this line after setting `config.load_defaults 5.2`.